# LIKE BINARY en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Quiero seleccionar un conjunto de resultados que, pasándole la opción por like, pero el resultado puede ser que este en minúscula o mayúscula.
Hice de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * FROM DocumentosAux WHERE numeroDocDisco like binary 'pbra';
```

También:

```
 SELECT * FROM DocumentosAux WHERE binary numeroDocDisco like 'pbra';
```

Pero ninguna de las formas da el resultado deseado, ya que podría esta escrito como Pbra, pBra, PBRA, etc.

Comment: Esto tiene que ver con la configuración `collation` de la tabla y/o la base de datos. ¿Puedes verificar cual es el `collate` de la tabla en cuestión y compartirlo? La forma de obtener la información varía según la herramienta utilizada. Pero normalmente hay manera de ver las propiedades de la tabla y obtenerlo allí. Sería algo como `utf8_bin` o `latin1_general_cs` , etc.

Comment: Collation era Latin, lo cambie a general_ci, quite el binary y funciono de maravilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DocumentosAux
 WHERE numeroDocDisco COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI like '%pbra%';
```

(Suponiendo que estés usando utf8 como menciona @sstan. Si no tendrá que usarse el *[collate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html)* correspondiente en su versión *case insensitive* `_ci`)

o

```
SELECT *
  FROM DocumentosAux
 WHERE lower(numeroDocDisco) like '%pbra%';
```

Por otro lado, si siempre quieres que sea insensible a mayúsculas, puedes cambiar la definición de la tabla y usar `COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI`.

Comment: Si, usando COLLATION GENERAL_CI en la configuracion me funciono

Comment: @Carlos puedes marcar esta respuesta como aceptada si solucionó tu problema

Comment: Ojo que no se puede aplicar el collate `utf8_general_ci` ciegamente a cualquier tabla, porque puede que la tabla no esté usando utf8 en absoluto. Por ejemplo, en el caso de OP, parece que los datos estaban usando `latin1` y no se puede hacer un salto de `latin1` a `utf8` así no mas. Tienes que mantenerlo dentro de la misma familia. Por eso, OP seguramente tuvo que usar `latin1_general_ci`, y no `utf8_general_ci`.